# Django the best way to create an edit modal form?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In one of my django app I have set the following architecture:

```
#models.py
    class Income(models.Model):
        price = models.DecimalField()
        quantity = models.DecimalField()
        date=models.DateField()



# forms.py
    class IncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Income
            fields = "__all__"

#views.py

def income_(request):
    elements = Income.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = IncomeForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             new_input = form.save()
    else :
       form = IncomeForm()
       elements = Income.objects.all()

    context= {
       'form': form,
       'elements':elements,
            }
    return render(request, "income/income.html", context)
```

In my income.html file I have set the following

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
 <form id="" method="post">                    
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
       {{form.quantity|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
       {{form.price|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
   <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
      {{form.date|as_crispy_field}}
   </div>
</div>
```

After that I have created a table that list all data filled.
Now I want to create a button for each row that open a modal form that give me the possibility to modify the specific data for each id dataset.

I have tried to perform it with an ajax call, but I have had difficults to perform the form and the type of data (becouse in this manner I don't have the possibility to use crispy form or the forms model of the django framework).

So my question is: **there is a simple way to achive my aim?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand from your question, you can try create a UpdateView in your view.py and redirect your html button with the object id to that view.

Updated answer-
since you are asking for simpler way implementing the edit page...

```
- models.py
    class Income(models.Model):
        price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
        quantity = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000)
        date = models.DateField()

- urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        path('income/', views.IncomeListView.as_view(), name='income'),
        path('income_edit/<int:pk>', views.IncomeEdit.as_view(), name='income-edit'),
    ]

- views.py
    class IncomeListView(ListView):
        model = Income
        template_name = 'income.html'


    class IncomeEdit(UpdateView):
        model = Income
        form_class = IncomeForm
        template_name = "income_form.html"

- forms.py
    class IncomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Income
            fields = '__all__'

- income.html
    <h1>Income List</h1>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>date</th>
        </tr>
    {% if income_list %}
      {% for income in income_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{income.id}}</td>
            <td>{{income.price}}</td>
            <td>{{income.quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{income.date}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'income-edit' income.id %}">Edit</a> </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    </table>

- income_form.html
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        {{ form.media }}
    </form>
```

please look into the class used for more information and understanding. hope this help =)

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: it would be helpful for me to understand your code better with your form.py and view.py.

Comment: Yep I have edited my answer I hope that you have all to give me an aswer :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. please look into the class used in this example for better understanding and modify them into your preference.

Comment: glad to hear that =)

Comment: @safi The income_form.html does not come up as a modal,but as a regular html page. Is this what you intended to do?